# Bubble sizes and distance between bubbles

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to build a bubble chart using chartjs v3.9 with bubble arrangment similar to something like this [image: desired bubbles arrangement].
The outcome I'm having right now is [image: low density of bubbles]

The arrangement I'm getting all the time is far away from the desired one. Bubbles are always on the other sides (according to the (x, y , radius) points. As the grid steps are scaling up to the parameters, a distance between bubbles remains the same. I was going through the documentation but couldn't spot any parameter that could use to place bubbles close to each other. Does anyone know if there is a way to increase a density of bubbles? What did I miss?

TIA do any hints/tips.
Kuba

Comment: After a break from the keyboard, I was able to find a way how to accomplish this.
Solution I came across is to add scales options (min, max). By playing with values for those parameters, I was able to put bubbles close to each other, like here: https://ibb.co/Vq6hF92

const config = {
  type: 'bubble',
  data: data,
  options: {
  
    scales: {
      x: {
        min: 26,
        max: 44,
      },
      y: {
        min: 30,
        max: 50,
      }
    }
  }
};